# Installing Headless on RHEL 6

Tags: rubygems, installation, yum, rhel, headless

I'm trying to install headless on RHEL 6, but all the information I've been able to dig up has been about installing it on RHEL 7, which may or may not require the same steps.

Does anyone have any insight on this? I know that I'm supposed to use kickstart, but that's about the extent of my knowledge on how to go about it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the question here just about how to automatically install a RHEL 6 system without a monitor/etc. attached? If so why is this tagged [gem]? Are you just looking to install a base system? A customized system? A VM? Is this part of a specific infrastructure?

Comment: I'm sorry let me clarify, this is about installing headless mode on a VM in order to create automated continuous testing with jenkins. I'm following this guide: https://blog.openshift.com/selenium-ruby-jenkins/

Comment: Are you trying to do this on an installed system or as part of a fresh system installation? kickstart is for fresh system installations. You also realize those directions are for RHEL 6, right? Also, the important details are the packages and not the specific directions. You need to install the correct prerequisite packages.

Comment: It's pretty fresh, and yeah I was looking at kickstart. The guide was working for me up until I was on the headles part, "sudo gem install headless", which is not working, although all the rest of the pre-requisites are installed. It's stating that it can't find a valid "headless" in any repository.

Comment: Installing the `selenium-webdriver` gem worked though? (I don't know anything about ruby or ruby gems but `headless` seems like a valid gem from what rubygems.org tells me. Perhaps you just need to force gem to update its list of available gems?)

Comment: It looks like the your gem sources are non-canonical, maybe because of some RHEL security policy. Please post output of `sudo gem sources --list`.

Comment: The output of `sudo gem sources --list` is only listing a proxy that points to the VB, it's not listing anything else other than that. 

Also, yes `selenium-webdriver` did install. I will definitely attempt to force update. This is my first time really working with gem and **RHEL** so I'm still trying to grasp everything. I'm used to **Debian / Gentoo** based systems, so this is a little different. 

Thanks guys!